# Client/server: how to synchronize UDP send and receive in C?

Tags: c, udp, client

I am writing a simple web server and client using UDP and so far:

- the programs can connect to each other,

  the client can send a request,

  the server can read the request,

  the server can recognize the client's IP address and client's port, and

  the server can send a message back to the client

**My problem is that my client code gets stuck waiting in the `rcvfrom` function, even after the server has sent a response.**

Here is the function that is supposed to pick up the server message and return the number of bytes read by the socket:

```
ssize_t receive_from_server(rdp_socket *rsocket, char *buffer, size_t buf_len){

  socklen_t sendsize = sizeof(rsocket->server_addr);
  bzero(&(rsocket->server_addr), sendsize);
  //STUCK HERE:
  return recvfrom(rsocket->sockfd, buffer, buf_len, 0,           
       (struct sockaddr*)&(rsocket->server_addr), &sendsize);
}
```

I set the sockopts for both `SO_SNDTIMEO` and `SO_RCVTIMEO` to timeout after a few seconds.

### Question:

In the short term future I will be adding acknowledgements (ACKs) for reliable data transfer. I imagine that missing ACKs could be the issue but I'm just wondering if, to the trained eye, it looks like a different problem.

Are ACKs necessary for a timeout to work?

How can I synchronize my client and server so that they can actually communicate with each other?

Comment: I've used TCP before to solve the same problem, but now I'm trying to do it using UDP and implementing my own measures to account for error control and packet loss.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong in this code or in your description. It would appear the problem is on the server side.

Comment: As Casey pointed out, there is not obvious mistake (as far as i can tell). Are you sure the data the server sent make it back to the client? Did you try wireshark, or some other tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since UDP does not provide reliability, you will need to implement retransmission of missing data. Since it looks like this is a client request server response model, the easiest retransmission implementation for you may be to resend the request when you time out waiting for the response, and wait for the response again. You may want to implement a retry counter and give up after a certain number of retries.

If the `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` socket options do not seem to be taking effect, it may be those options are not implemented for that type of socket. Check the return value of the `setsockopt()`call  to make sure they succeeded.

As a workaround, you can change your `receive_from_server()` function to use `poll()` or `select()` to wait for a readable event for some amount of time, instead of blocking in `recvfrom()`.

```
ssize_t receive_from_server(rdp_socket *rsocket, char *buffer, size_t buf_len){
  struct pollfd pfd = { rsocket->sockfd, POLLIN };
  int pollresult = poll(&pfd, 1, RECV_TIMEOUT_SECONDS * 1000);

  if (pollresult > 0) {
    socklen_t sendsize = sizeof(rsocket->server_addr);
    bzero(&(rsocket->server_addr), sendsize);

    return recvfrom(rsocket->sockfd, buffer, buf_len, MSG_DONTWAIT,           
      (struct sockaddr*)&(rsocket->server_addr), &sendsize);
  }

  if (pollresult == 0) {
      errno = ETIME;
  }

  return -1;
}
```